# Codeigniter: Unable to differentiate between admin and member page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is the login controller code:

```
public function login_validation(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('model_users');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|alpha_numeric|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => 1
            );

            if($this->model_users->get_status($data['username'])){
                $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'status' => 'member',
                'is_logged_in' => 1
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('member');
            } else {
                $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'status' => 'admin',
                'is_logged_in' => 1
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('admin');
            }
        } else {
            $this->login();
        }
    }
```

This is the admin controller:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            $status = $this->session->userdata('status');
            if ($status == 'member'){
                redirect('main/restricted');
            }
redirect('main/restricted');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Admin Page'
        );
        $this->load->view("header", $data);
        $this->load->view("admin");
        $this->load->view("nav");
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
}
```

This is the member controller code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Member extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            $status = $this->session->userdata('status');
            if ($status == 'admin'){
                redirect('main/restricted');
            }
redirect('main/restricted');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Member Page'
        );
        $this->load->view("header", $data);
        $this->load->view("member");
        $this->load->view("nav");
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
}
```

I am wondering why after the member login, they are able to go to the admin page, and also after the admin have logged in they are also able to access the member page.

I would want it to work as, after the member log in the member will only be able to access the member page. After the admin log in the admin will only be able to access the admin page.

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
```

I think your `if` condition returns `false`.

You did not write anything for `else`condition.Write some code for  `else`.
If your `if` condition is `false` everyone can have access for member and admin controller.

Make sure your `if` condition returns `true`

i think your code may be like this

```
 if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
 {
        //write code for not loged user
 }
 else
 {
      $status = $this->session->userdata('status');
        if ($status == 'member'){
            redirect('main/restricted');
        }
   }
```

Comment: This answer seems to be correct. Your IF statement is checking to see whether the ``is_logged_in`` session variable isn't present by virtue of the logical '!' operator. Based on your login code, that variable will be set whenever someone successfully logs in so any checks for the ``status`` session variable will not be performed and, thus, any logged in user will be able to see both restricted areas.

Comment: I think his problem is not in the login process, but the process after login which is member can access admin area by inserting the admin page URL directly and vice versa, am i wrong? @Outliers

Comment: @stormrage What I mean is that the checks that are being performed on both controllers are to see if the session variable isn't present and then allowing access due to the absence of an ``else`` statement. I mention the login code only because that session variable is set when login is successful so both of his controllers' ``IF`` statements will never check the ``status`` session variable because they will always evaluate to true when a user is logged in.

Comment: Ohh okay i got it now, yup i got it working. Because i forgot to assign a value for status therefore it wasn't working from the start. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare session status with 'member' or 'admin' instead of just checking if it is set.
In Admin controller:

```
$status = $this->session->userdata('status')
if ($status == 'member'){
    redirect('main/restricted');
}
```

and similarly compare with 'admin' in member controller.

Comment: Hi! I have edited the code already however it is still not working.

Comment: Does your session work? Is the library loaded? I hope you have made sure that session is working fine. May be `$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')` may be returning false always even if user is loggedin.

Comment: Yup my session is working because if a user is not logged in and try to access the member or admin page, he/she will be redirected to the restricted page